# Autobahn|Python Twisted server that checks API key and disconnects clients

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I want to add a simple API key check to an Autobahn Python WebSocket server. The server should check the key in the HTTP header of a client and disconnect clients that don't have the correct key.

I have figured out a solution to this, but I'm not sure it is the best solution (see below). If anyone has suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API Docs](http://autobahn.ws/python/reference/autobahn.websocket.html#autobahn.websocket.protocol.WebSocketServerProtocol.onConnect) for the onConnect method:

> Throw autobahn.websocket.types.ConnectionDeny when you don’t want to accept the WebSocket connection request.

You can see this done on line 117 of one of the examples [here](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/multiproto/server1.py).

I have tested this and it does **not** close the connection cleanly. However you are terminating a connection with an unauthenticated client so you should not want to go through a closing handshake.

The onClose callback takes a wasClean argument which allows you to differentiate between clean and unclean connection closures.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to check the HTTP header after the client has connected to the server and to close the connection if the client does not have a valid API key.

```
MY_API_KEY = u'12345'

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        # Check API Key
        if 'my-api-key' not in self.http_headers or\
            self.http_headers['my-api-key'] != MY_API_KEY:
            # Disconnect the client
            print('Missing/Invalid Key')
            self.sendClose( 4000, u'Missing/Invalid Key')

        # Register client
        self.factory.register(self)
```

I found that if I close the connection inside onConnect, I get an error saying that I cannot close a connection that has not yet connected. The above solution closes cleanly on the client side, but behaves oddly on the server side. The log output is

```
dropping connection: None
Connection to/from tcp4:127.0.0.1:51967 was aborted locally
_connectionLost: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionAborted'>: Connection was aborted locally, using.
    ]
WebSocket connection closed: None
```

Is the reason the close message is None on the server side that the server closed the connection and the client did not send back a reason? Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:**
I have accepted Henry Heath's answer because it seems to be the officially supported solution, even though it does not close the connection cleanly. Using `autobahn.websocket.types.ConnectionDeny`, the solution becomes

```
from autobahn.websocket.types import ConnectionDeny
MY_API_KEY = u'12345'

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {}".format(request.peer))
        # Check API Key
        if 'my-api-key' not in request.headers or\
            request.headers['my-api-key'] != MY_API_KEY:
            # Disconnect the client
            print('Missing/Invalid Key')
            raise ConnectionDeny( 4000, u'Missing/Invalid Key')

    def onOpen(self):
        # Register client
        self.factory.register(self)
```

Note that within onConnect, HTTP headers are accessible with request.headers whereas within onOpen, they are accessible with self.http_headers.